# Зачем нужен метод возврата абсолютной величины (abs)?

Tags: java

Зачем нужен метод `abs`? Если я правильно понимаю, он возвращает то число что передано ему в параметре. Если так, то зачем пропускать это число через метод - разве нельзя это число напрямую использовать?

Вопрос возник из задачи: найти из двух переданных аргументов ближайшее к 10. В условии задачи рекомендуют использовать метод `abs`:

```
public static int abs(int a) {
    if (a < 0) {
        return -a;
    } else {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не нравится функция - не используйте. Вопрос то в чем...

Comment: Нет, неправильно понимаете. Если число `a` отрицательное, то возвращается не само число (`a`), а его абсолютная величина (`-a`). То есть для `-5` метод возвращает `5`, а это уже совсем другое число. И в некоторых задачах удобнее работать с абсолютными величинами.

Comment: Вот в чём действительно смысла нет - так это в написании своего `abs` когда есть `Math.abs`.

Comment: В школе в пятом классе не проходили модуль |x|? Так вот abs(x) и есть этот модуль |x|. Потому что в правилах языках программирования обычно не возможно записать функцию привычными символами как в школьной тетрадке. Модуль иными словами называется абсолютным значением, отсюда и название функции - abs.

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за ваши разъяснения. @Regent тебе еще за правку вопроса спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот как раз в такой задаче `abs` крайне полезен:

```
public statis int nearestTo10(int a, int b) {
   return abs(a-10) > abs(b-10) ? b : a;
}
```

Если убрать `abs`, то получатся разные результаты для пар (12,9) и (9,12)